# MySQL query to get all photos

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, they are `properties` and `property_images`. The fields in properties and property_images tables are as below

**properties**

```
property_id 
name
address
city
type
```

**property_images**

```
prop_img_id
photoname
property_id
```

I have a query to get the results from both the tables. But when I run the query I get only one image for each property. But I get the count of images right. I want to get all photos for a property in the query. The query I have is this:

```
SELECT *, photo, COUNT(property_photo.photo) as photocount
FROM properties LEFT JOIN
     property_photo
     ON properties.property_id = property_photo.property_id
GROUP BY properties.property_id
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(pp.photoname) as photocount,
       GROUP_CONCAT(pp.photoname SEPARATOR '|')
FROM properties p LEFT JOIN
     property_photo pp
     ON p.property_id = pp.property_id
GROUP BY p.property_id
LIMIT 6;
```

This puts the names of the photos in a string, with a vertical bar separating each name.

Answer (score 0):

use inner query to get count and then join it with photo property

```
    select tt.photo,t.photocount from property_photo tt inner join 
(SELECT p.property_id, COUNT(pp.photo) as photocount 
  FROM properties p LEFT JOIN property_photo pp
 ON p.property_id = pp.property_id GROUP BY p.property_id ) t on t.property_id=tt.property_id;
```